# undefined is not an object(evaluating'_react2.Proptypes.store')?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build the taxi booking app. From i get the error 
`undefined is not an object (evaluating'_react2.Proptypes.store')`. I have tried all the other solutions in previously asked but it was not helpful. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes} from "react";
import { Router } from "react-native-router-flux";
import scenes from "../routes/scenes";



import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export default class AppContainer extends Component{
static propTypes =  {
        store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
render(){
    return(
        <Provider store = {this.props.store}>
            <Router scenes = {scenes} />
        </Provider>
        )
}
}
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "TaxiApp",
"version": "0.0.7",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
"test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
"native-base": "^2.3.5",
"prop-types": "^15.6.0",
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
"react-native": "0.51.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.24",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "22.0.4",
"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
"jest": "22.0.4",
"react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code that uses `AppContainer`?

Answer (score 0):

Ever since react version 16.0.0 forward, prop types cannot be taken from React itself as you did on the first line. You need to do the following;

1. `npm install prop-types --save`
2. Add the following import and remove the PropTypes from first line:
   `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

After this, it should work like a charm.